# Falling Chimney using Lagranges Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

There is this interesting problem for a falling chimney, in which you want to determine where it is most likely to break first.
I am well aware of the 'classical' solutions (e.g. http://www.physics.harvard.edu/uploads/files/undergrad/probweek/sol49.pdf).
I was now wondering how one would get a similar result without using the concept of torque directly, but as a general result from using the Lagrangian of the chimney (Would that just be the ordinary one of a rotating rod in a uniform gravitational field, or are there extra terms to be included?) and the subsequent equations of motion.